# Writeback partition secuirty in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

I have a writeback partition working pretty well in a cube. The users access it through Excel 2010. At the moment there are 3 measures in the cube. I'd like to only give users access to writeback to 2 of them while being able to read all 3. Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm very much an MDX novice if MDX is involved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all 3 of your measures in the same measure group?  I don't think you can choose only some measures in the writeback measure group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failproof way to prevent those users from writing to your measure is by including those in a special Role with writeback access. In the tab "Cell Data", check the box "Enable read/write permissions", and in the field below "Allow reading and writing of cube content" you can set an expression to limit the write measures, such as:

```
(Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[X] OR Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[Y])
```

In the upper field, that enables read access, allow access to all three measures:

```
(
Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[X] OR 
Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[Y] OR
Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[Z] 
)
```

They will have a weird message saying that the cell was blocked, but at least you'll prevent them from writing to your beloved measure.

Another approach would be: create a Calculated measure `([Measures].[ZZ])` based on the one you want to hide `([Measures].[Z])`. SSAS won't let the user writeback on a calculated measure. Make sure you hide the original by marking it VISIBLE = 0.

Answer (score 0):

@mmarie is correct...if the measures are all in the same partition, then you'll need to move the 2 for writeback into a separate measure group. You can do this by creating separate views in the relational DW or via named queries in the DSV. Since both measure groups will have the same dimensionality (because they are based on the same table) SSDT will give you a warning - just ignore it ;-)